# Изменение в конфигурационном файле

Tags: json, golang, configuration

```go
//{"AccessToken":"string", "Users": [1, 2, 3], "Groups":[1,2,3], "Timeout":123, "DB":"string", "ProfilePath":"string"}
type Configuration struct {
    AccessToken string `json:"AccessToken"`
    DB          string `json:"DB"`
    Groups      []int  `json:"Groups"`
    ProfilePath string `json:"ProfilePath"`
    Timeout     int    `json:"Timeout"`
    Users       []int  `json:"Users"`
}

func ReadConfig(conf string) UserConf {
    file, _ := os.Open(conf)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    configuration := UserConf{}
    err := decoder.Decode(&configuration)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    }
    return configuration
}
```

Так мы читаем конфиг. Помогите примером как перезаписать конфиг добавив в Configuration.Users еще одного юзера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись JSON в файл делается такими же функциями из `os` и `json`:

```
func WriteConfig(fileName string, configuration UserConf) error {
  file, err := os.Create(fileName)
  if err != nil {
    return err;
  }
  defer file.Close()
  return json.NewEncoder(file).Encode(configuration)
}
```